# Connection Pooling - SharePoint 2007

Tags: .net, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

How to check/confirm that whether SQL connection pooling is enabled for a sharepoint 2007 web-application ?

Answer (score 0):

It is built into the SharePoint DAL.  I've used SQL Profiler to verify in the past.

You can see that the connections are re-used when viewing the profiler logs.

Comment: Oops, I am not a SQL guy so can you tell me that how to verify this using SQL profiler? ....